# Mapping JSON to Class automatically - design issue

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I am using a certain API which returns JSON data in the following format:

```
entities {
    entity#1 { [property#1:value, property#2:value] },
    entity#2 { [property#3:value, property#4:value] }
}
```

The entities in this JSON are defined manually, which means each entity can have unique properties. What is the best way to parse this kind of data?

At the moment, I'm making a unique class for each entity that I define on the API however the amount of entities that I define could be well over 100.

Is there a way in Java to create a single class that would have the shared properties pre-defined, and then add properties to that same class on runtime?

Comment: Java is a `strictly typed` language, which forbids dynamic properties. Altough you can cheat a bit by making a logic which holds all the properties (`List`) and then can be accessed via a method

Comment: You can have unique class with all properties and use `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)` to avoid the unexisted propesrties in the JSON

Comment: (The Java's Runtime Environment way of associating a single value to each of any number of *somethings* is [Map<key, value>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#method.summary).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your entities probably share some of the common properties and differ in others. It that case a decent compromise approach would be having a class containing the common properties as class fields. The rest needs to be stored in a Map a  key-value pairs. This allows you to have at least some class structure without having a hundred of slightly different classes.

Something like

```
private String someProperty;
private boolean someOtherCommonProperty;
...

private Map<String, Object> allTheOtherProperties;
```

For deserialization details check this article:
http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-map

Specifically 4.2. Map Deserialization

Comment: probably `Map<String, Object>` would be better

Comment: Is there a Java implementation somewhere that could do this sort of mapping from JSON->Class automatically (I mean the map part)

Comment: Updated my answer with a link.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could use Jackson to do deserialization (http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization) and define a custom mapper that would deserialize the dynamic variables into a `Map` instead.